# IllegalAccess Error JPA

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, ejb, entitymanager

hey i take a illegalaccess error, with the EntityManager

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: SessionBean/Accounts
```

the Client starts a methode on

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  sessionBean.connect();
  sessionBean.create();


}
```

The Sessionbean

```
@Override
public void create() {
    em.persist(new Accounts("Test", "test"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to call a method that it does not have access to. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html)

You probably have an old copy of your `Accounts.class` floating around, or it's defined differently in more than one jar on your runtime classpath.

Comment: now i have another problem, i change to XML save System and now i get